# Sending an Email using Google Doc (to HTML) with Data Inserts from Response Sheet

Tags: html-email

I have a Google Doc template that pulls in information from a Form Responses sheet. The template is below:

Email Template

[image: 1]

The 'name' would populate but the table would not.

I have the following script to declare some column header names as constants:

const DEPARTMENT = 'School Department';

const PHONE = 'Phone';

const NC_LOC = 'No Cite Location';

const DATE_NC = 'Date of No Cite';

const TIME_NC = 'Start and End Time of Event';

Does anyone know why the table will not populate based on these constants? I've already executed 'function createForm' to first populate data for the table.

Comment: About `The 'name' would populate but the table would not.`, when I saw `I have the following script to declare some column header names as constants:`, I cannot understand your current script. I apologize for this. Can you provide your current script for correctly replicating `The 'name' would populate but the table would not.`?

Comment: This is a part of my current script:

const NAME = 'Name';
const DEPARTMENT = 'Department';
const PERMIT_TYPE_REQUEST = 'What type of permit are you requesting?';

function createForm() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let form = FormApp.create('FORM)
      .setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId())
      .setAllowResponseEdits(true);

  form.addTextItem().setTitle(NAME);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle(DEPARTMENT);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle(PERMIT_TYPE_REQUEST);

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you provide your script, please add it to your question. Because when the script is put in the comment, the readability becomes low. If you can understand it, I'm glad.